# Genesis 6:3 Is it talking about Spirit or spirit?

Tags: genesis, spirit

> “Then the Lord said, "My Spirit shall not abide in man forever, for he is flesh: his days shall be 120 years."”
>   ‭‭Genesis‬ ‭6:3‬ ‭ESV‬

Is there a direct connection between the presence of His Spirit and length of life? Or is it saying that because He is removing His Spirit He is also reducing the length of life?

Comment: Then the Lord said, "My Spirit does not abide in the undomesticated (of Elam). He is indeed wretched: his days shall be 120 years." ‭‭ (120 years till they become domesticated).

Answer (score 0):

Peace.

The “sons of God” were men who had the Spirit of God within them as compared to the rest of the world which didn’t (the natural man).

There were 2 types of people in the world (as today also):  those that have the Spirit of God dwelling within them and those natural men of the world who do not have this.

The fleshly mind of those of the world are not subject to the law of God (because they do not have His Spirit dwelling within them).  They cannot be subject to it without His Spirit within them. They do not delight in His commands and cannot as it is the Spirit within us that gives us the willingness and ability to do them. We delight in His commands while the world (the natural men) does not.

> *Romans 8:6-9 KJV (6)  For to be carnally minded is death; but to be spiritually minded is life and peace. (7)  **Because the carnal mind is
>   enmity against God: for it is not subject to the law of God, neither
>   indeed can be.** (8)  So then they that are in the flesh cannot please
>   God. (9)  **But ye are not in the flesh, but in the Spirit, if so be
>   that the Spirit of God dwell in you. Now if any man have not the
>   Spirit of Christ, he is none of his**.*

The Spirit of God strived within those sons of God as these men did not always live according to His Spirit but instead continuously lived after the flesh:  “he is also flesh”…that is, these men continuously lived after the flesh and not after His Spirit.

> *Genesis 6:3 KJV (3)  **And the LORD said, My spirit shall not always strive with man, for that he also is flesh**: yet his days shall be an
>   hundred and twenty years.*

There was an internal struggle of God’s Spirit within the sons of God who were living after the flesh as every imagination of the thoughts of their heart was only evil….continually evil (even though they could have lived after the Spirit and did good).

> *Genesis 6:5-6 KJV (5)  And GOD saw that the wickedness of man was great in the earth, and that every imagination of the thoughts of his
>   heart was only evil continually.*

They grieved His Spirit.

> *(6)  And it repented the LORD that he had made man on the earth, **and it grieved him at his heart**.*

But not so with “Noah” which means “rest/quiet” .  The Spirit of God found “rest” within Noah as His Spirit did not struggle within him.  Noah found grace in the eyes of the LORD.

> *Genesis 6:8 KJV (8)  **But Noah found grace in the eyes of the LORD**.*

Today, people can still “grieve” the Spirit of God by continuously living after the flesh (living in bitterness, wrath, evil speaking, etc) rather than being led with the Spirit that dwells within them.

> *Ephesians 4:29-32 KJV (29)  Let no corrupt communication proceed out of your mouth, but that which is good to the use of edifying, that it
>   may minister grace unto the hearers. (30)  **And grieve not the holy
>   Spirit of God, whereby ye are sealed unto the day of redemption.** (31) 
>   Let all bitterness, and wrath, and anger, and clamour, and evil
>   speaking, be put away from you, with all malice: (32)  And be ye kind
>   one to another, tenderhearted, forgiving one another, even as God for
>   Christ's sake hath forgiven you.*

His Spirit will not always strive with those who live after the flesh (he is also flesh) just as He did not back then for if we continue to live after the flesh, we shall die.

> *Romans 8:12-14 KJV (12)  T**herefore, brethren, we are debtors, not to the flesh, to live after the flesh**.*

We must (through His Spirit) mortify the deeds of the body so that we may live.  His Spirit will not always strive within us....in those who continue to live after the flesh and not after His Spirit.

> *(13)  **For if ye live after the flesh, ye shall die**: but if ye through the Spirit do mortify the deeds of the body, ye shall live.*

The “sons of God” must put to death the deeds of the body and live after His Spirit as He will not always strive with those who do not.

> *(14)  For as many as are led by the Spirit of God, **they are the sons of God.***

The Spirit strives within us if we continue to live after the flesh.  There is no “rest” for His Spirit within those who continue to live after the flesh.  The Spirit and flesh are contrary to one another.  There is an internal struggle within between the Spirit of God and the lusts of the flesh in those who do not crucify (in Christ) the flesh with its affections and lusts.

> *Galatians 5:16-26 KJV (16)  This I say then, Walk in the Spirit, and ye shall not fulfil the lust of the flesh. (17)  **For the flesh lusteth
>   against the Spirit, and the Spirit against the flesh: and these are
>   contrary the one to the other: so that ye cannot do the things that ye
>   would.** (18)  But if ye be led of the Spirit, ye are not under the law.
>   (19)  **Now the works of the flesh are manifest, which are these;**
>   Adultery, fornication, uncleanness, lasciviousness, (20)  Idolatry,
>   witchcraft, hatred, variance, emulations, wrath, strife, seditions,
>   heresies, (21)  Envyings, murders, drunkenness, revellings, and such
>   like: of the which I tell you before, as I have also told you in time
>   past, that they which do such things shall not inherit the kingdom of
>   God. (22)  **But the fruit of the Spirit is love, joy, peace,
>   longsuffering, gentleness, goodness, faith,** (23)  Meekness,
>   temperance: against such there is no law. (24)  And they that are
>   Christ's have crucified the flesh with the affections and lusts. (25) 
>   **If we live in the Spirit, let us also walk in the Spirit.** (26)  Let us
>   not be desirous of vain glory, provoking one another, envying one
>   another.*

We cannot become a "friend of the world" in these things.  Friendship of this world is enmity....hostility/opposition...with God.  There is an internal struggle with those who have a friendship with this world.

> *James 4:4 KJV (4)  **Ye adulterers and adulteresses, know ye not that the friendship of the world is enmity with God? whosoever therefore
>   will be a friend of the world is the enemy of God**.*

That is what the "sons of God" did.  They became "friends of the world" by marrying the "daughters of men"....daughters of the natural men of the world.  Then there was "enmity with God" as there was a struggle of His Spirit within the sons of God who continually lived after the flesh.

> *Genesis 6:1-4 KJV (1)  And it came to pass, when men began to multiply on the face of the earth, and daughters were born unto them,
>   (2)  **That the sons of God saw the daughters of men that they were
>   fair; and they took them wives of all which they chose. (3)  And the
>   LORD said, My spirit shall not always strive with man**, for that he
>   also is flesh: yet his days shall be an hundred and twenty years. (4) 
>   There were giants in the earth in those days; and also after that,
>   when the sons of God came in unto the daughters of men, and they bare
>   children to them, the same became mighty men which were of old, men of
>   renown.*

Men "marry" doctrines and commandments of men today and fight each other over them.  They become friends of the world in their envy and strife as they war and fight over them in their quarreling over who is "accounted the greatest" among them.  They behave just like the world who also fights and wars over their laws, constitutions, governments, etc (laws made by natural men who do not have the Spirit).  The handwriting of "ordinances" (various church dogmas) are contrary to us getting along with one another as many fight over their respective "handwritings" which are patterned after the world.  They are against us.  Fortunately, the Lord forgives us as those handwritings are nailed to His cross.

> *Colossians 2:13-15 KJV (13)  And you, being dead in your sins and the uncircumcision of your flesh, hath he quickened together with him,
>   **having forgiven you all trespasses; (14)  Blotting out the handwriting
>   of ordinances that was against us, which was contrary to us, and took
>   it out of the way, nailing it to his cross;** (15)  And having spoiled
>   principalities and powers, he made a shew of them openly, triumphing
>   over them in it.*

Comment: I’m sorry but I don’t subscribe to the Augustinian sons of G d being men that doesn’t fit with Scripture unless you think men were able to fly in the sky psalm 89

Comment: Were men able to fly עוף : Jud 4:21 , 1 Sa 14:28, 1 Sa 14:31, 2 Sa 21:15... ?  No, But actually the word is used to be faint almost to death. So before rejecting it because you misinterpret it hyper-literally, there is room for the Sons of God being men.

Comment: There is room but I don’t ascribe to it, also due to a number of other passages including but not limited to Deu 32:8 LXX and DDS version. Also Jeremiah Micaiah Elijah and Elisha were about to stand in the council of Elohim, this goes more to your argument but then Psalm 82 says they will die like men, which if they were men, were they immortal prior or were they not men?

Answer (score 0):

The most sensible way to understand this, I think, is that the 'natural' (arguably focusing on the root sense 'physical') man is the animal component of the human nature. That is to say, man minus spiritual guidance, help, grace. As such, if the natural man cannot understand the spiritual things, and heretics and reprobate people cannot understand spiritual things, he is implying they have no spiritual guidance, development, or grace. They are just the bare animal human, without the higher faculty of the spirit (not that they don't have a spirit, since a spirit is what means the difference between a human and a cadaver).

From the context of Genesis 6:3 it is clear that 'my Spirit contending in Man' refers to the keeping-alive of human beings. It is the same *ruah*—spirit, or breath—spoken of when Adam is 'breathed into' with the breath of life—that is, a metaphor meanning 'was made alive by the power of God.' And that 'not forever ... his days shall be a hundred and twenty years' is answers to 'my Spirit will not contend forever in.' It is not about the loss of a Golden Era before which God's Spirit strove in man.

### Appendix

לעלם (l'olam) does not necessarily mean for *eternity*, but multiple ages or 'eons.' It comes from the primitive idea of 'horizon.' Hence, God simply means 'my Spirit won't strive in man for a great number of centuries, as with Adam etc., from henceforth his days shall be at most one hundred and twenty years.'

Comment: So you are saying that it’s not the Spirit that indwelt the Genesis 6 man and prior, it was merely the spirit or the ruach, hence why you associate this ruach with life.

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. *Ruah* is simply the Hebrew word for spirit. As such, it's not evident whether it is the Holy Spirit that makes a man live, or the general life-giving force. In any case, Nicene Christianity professes belief in "the Holy Spirit, the Lord and Giver of life."

Comment: Because if it’s the Spirit then how do you receive Acts 2 what you already have?

Comment: Interesting that the Father is equated to giver of life yet all things were made and sustained by Jesus. And the Holy Spirit is also referenced as being the Spirit of Christ. Furthermore in my other thread it complicates the issue when Ezekiel claims we receive a new spirit but some claim that it’s merely the quickening of the existing spirit by the Holy Spirit. Or as you would have it, receive guidance for spiritual discernment of the things of G d.

Comment: Also the reason I don’t fully accept that it was merely the spirit that related to life itself that is being referenced is because if I take your reasoning that one needs the Holy Spirit to discern the things of G d then how did Cain speak to G d? How did Noah discern what to do and how did Enoch walk with G d? This would imply they interacted with G d on a non spiritual level but physical because if it were at the soul level it would be indiscernible. I think it was the Spirit that G d took away because G d reverts back to His initial design in Acts 2. G d doesn’t change it was good already.

Comment: I think that's a good point; and reprobates certainly live, but also certainly have nothing to do with God's Spirit. Here spirit might be seen simply as the breath of life spoken of, that even animals have. Over and against Paul's use of natural [in contradistinction to spiritual] man. However, Acts 2 is about the gifts of the Holy Spirit as well as about receiving Him Himself spiritually, since it is clear the Gentiles before even being properly converted were given gifts, which then prompted the Apostles to admit them into the church.

Comment: For Acts 2 see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ztqdmCIGSDY) comprehensive treatment of the 'gifts of the Holy Spirit.'

Comment: "because if I take your reasoning that one needs the Holy Spirit to discern the things of G d then how did Cain speak to G d?" The very fact that he is seen as having done evil presupposes the previous state of having the power of God (the Spirit) to do the good instead which he did not do. The Spirit departs when one sins. "For wisdom will not enter into a malicious soul, nor dwell in a body subject to sins. For the Holy Spirit of discipline will flee from the deceitful, and will withdraw himself from thoughts that are without understanding, and he shall not abide when iniquity cometh in."

Comment: It appears your view of Cain is that he was in a state of innocence or without sin like Jesus who possibly didn’t have an a Adamic body  “Curds and honey He shall eat, that He may know to refuse the evil and choose the good.”
‭‭Isaiah‬ ‭7:15‬ ‭NKJV‬‬
And when he committed the murder then Cain sinned but then regarding the sacrifice Cain should have been received, unless wrong sacrifices are not sinful.

Comment: In the Old Testament period, no regeneration occurred. As such, actual perfection never occurred (there were no 'saved' people, except that they were destined to be saved whenever Jesus went to free them from /Abraham's Bosom, "that apart from us they should not be made perfect"), only God's forbearance. So I don't mean the indwelling of the Spirit as in believers in Christ, or to the same degree, but the sufficient help of God to be good, and sacrifice provided virtual forgiveness, in view of the merits of Christ. Jesus is a son of Adam, so he did have an 'Adamic' body in that sense.